# QTableWidget: how to create dynamically within a tab, and populate them

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to generate a few dynamic qTableWidgets within a new tab. On my main window I have a tab called Dashboard populated with a button to refresh my data. Once clicked, I generate a list of dataframes (number can vary) and I would like to print out these dataframes into various QTableWidgets within a new tab.

```
class MyQtApp(main.Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyQtApp, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.qDashboard_refreshdata_btn.clicked.connect(self.refresh_data)

    def refresh_data(self):
        #upon refresh, I destroy all tabs except the mian one, ie Dashboard
        if self.tabManager.count() > 1: #tabManager is the qTabWidget
            for i in range(1, self.tabManager.count()):
                self.tabManager.removeTab(i)

         tabName = 'abc'
         d1 = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3': [1, 2], 'col4': [3, 4]}
         df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
         d2 = {'col1': [5, 6], 'col2': [7, 8], 'col3': [9, 2], 'col4': [78, 4]}
         df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
         df_list = [df1, df2]
         header_label = ['My first Column', 'My second Column']

         self.addingTab = MyTab(df_list, len(df_list), header_label) 
         #this will be changed to a list of MyTab objects, to generate a dynamic number of tabs
         self.tabManager.addTab(self.addingTab, str(trade))
         #self.addingTab.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    util.patchAsyncio()
    util.useQt()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    qt_app = MyQtApp()
    qt_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

And here is the class MyTab which controls the aspect of a new Tab

```
class MyTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, listData, nbComponents, headerComponents, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.Table = []
        for i in range(nbComponents):
            self.Table.append(QtWidgets.QTableWidget(i, 0))
            self.Table[i].setObjectName("table_" + str(i))
            self.Table[i].setColumnCount(len(headerComponents))
            self.Table[i].setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['{:.2f}'.format(x) for x in headerComponents])
            self.Table[i].setRowCount(len(listData[i]))
            self.loaddata(listData[i], self.Table[i])
            self.layout.addWidget(self.Table[i], i, 0)

    def loaddata(self, df, tableNb):
        for x in range(len(df)):
            for y in range(tableNb.columnCount()):
                tableNb.setItem(x, y, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(df.iloc[x, y])))
```

I use a QGridLayout, because I would like to have all the qTableWidgets vertically aligned on the first column of the layout and later on add a plotly graph on the second column.

The current issue with this code is that it seems the QTableWidgets are correctly created but they "stacked" on top of each other. Ideally I would like to have them one below the other...

Edit: I tried to add the following before "def loaddata" in MyTab class:

```
tabtoadd.layout.addWidget(self.Table[i], i, 0)
```

but then the tab is created and no qTableWidget is produced

Comment: You seem to be very confused on the usage of widgets and classes. For instance, your `MyTab` is never used as a proper widget, still you set a layout on it, but then reparent its children to another. That `tabtoadd` is completely pointless and wrong; just add table widgets to the layout and add that `MyTab` instance either by calling `tabObj.addTab(self, ...)` or, better, in `refresh_data()` with `self.tabManager.addTab(self.addingtab, ...)` (which is a more proper way to do things, as children should not add themselves to a parent like this).

Comment: Thanks @musicamante I edited my code in the OP to reflect what I understood from your comment. Naively I intended to use the MyTab class as a generic template for the few similar tabs I intend to add. Currently I am not showing any qTableWidget on the new tab (it does get created) but I suspect I am still mixed up things with the layout (?)

Comment: You removed the most important part, which is the `self` argument in `QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)`. Without that, the layout is not set (unless `self.setLayout(layout)` is explicitly called, which is the same). Also, you should normally not overwrite `self.layout`, since that is a dynamic property of all QWidgets.